# Qt QByteArray unsigned datatype

Tags: c++, qt, unsigned

I need to send data over rs232,but I'm facing a problem.
When I send byte representing integer over 128, it looks like QByteArray changes the content I feed it:

```
uchar uc_array[]={0x41,0xAA}; //65 170
QByteArray qb_array = QByteArray();
qb_array.append(uc_array[0]);
qb_array.append(uc_array[1]);
cout<<(uint)qb_array[0]<<endl //65
cout<<(uint)qb_array[1]<<endl //4294967210
```

Why

```
 cout<<(uint)qb_array[1]<<endl
```

doesn't print 170, but 4294967210 instead ?

Comment: I think you need to call it like: `cout << (uint)(uchar)qb_array[1] << endl;` instead.

Comment: Yes it prints 170,but can I be sure that if I send qb_array over serial it will send 0xAA?I mean 10101010

Comment: I think it will depend on how do you send that data.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my explanation of why you print 4294967210 instead of 170, which is your original question:

1. `qb_array[1]` returns a `signed char` type with 0xAA value
2. When you cast a `signed char` to `uint` type:

   - the value is first promoted to `int` type, keeping the sign: it becomes 0xFFFFFFAA
   - then it is interpreted as unsigned, so 4294967210 in decimal format.
3. Printing this value in decimal format gives 4294967210.